# Android media notification large icon doesn't change

Tags: java, android, android-mediasession

I have a media notification and a large icon, my code successfully loads the image first time, but image doesn't changes second time. My code was working in Android 8.1.0, currently I'm using Android 12 and it doesn't work.

```
    mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
            .putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, image)
            .putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ART, image)
            .putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, -1L)
            .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE,BASLIK)
            .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST,ISIM)
            .build());

    stateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder();
    stateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACT
    stateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 1.0f);
    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build());

    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(BASLIK)
            .setContentText(ISIM)
            .setLargeIcon(image)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_previous, "Previous", prevPendingIntent)
            .addAction(icon, "Play", playPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next, "Next", nextPendingIntent)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2)
                    .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken()));
            
    notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(CHANNEL_ID), notification.build());
```

I tried removing MediaStyle and it worked, images successfully changed each time but I need to use MediaStyle. I'm sure about updating the notification, title and song name changes but image doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding `metadata.putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, duration);`. `duration` variable should be `long` and it should always get updated.